# Glide library RequestOptions inspection results error: The result of 'diskCacheStrategy' is not used

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Android studio show an error after Analyse -> Inspect Code on diskCacheStrategy as "the result of 'diskCacheStrategy' is not used".

My codes are like that:

This method at in Utils.java

```
public static RequestOptions getDiskCacheRequestOptions(){
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL); //related redline error
    return requestOptions;
}
```

It is at different java files.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .applyDefaultRequestOptions(Utils.getDiskCacheRequestOptions())
    .load(mImageUrl))
    .into(mImageView);
```

Why android studio shows error message?

One solution to remove warning but my mind is confused because diskCacheStrategy method looks as setter method when isAutoCloneEnabled == false.

```
 requestOptions = 
 requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
```

Comment: `return requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);`

Comment: or `return new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);`

Comment: indeed: simple oneliner

Comment: return new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) uncovers another error as Non-static method can not be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT);
```

instead of DiskCacheStrategy.ALL

Comment: I guess DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT is at old versions of Glide. 4.2.0 does not have it. Anyways I don't get that what kind of relation is this answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Glide version 4.6.1

```
RequestOptions getDiskCacheRequestOptions() {
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL); 

    return requestOptions;
}
```